# GAE - Error refreshing OAuth2 token

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-php-client

I have a PHP application running on GAE. It connects to Cloud Datastore using the Google PHP library (v0.6.7). This connection works fine most of the times, but occasionaly I get the following error, indicating that an error occurred when trying to refresh the OAuth2 token.

```
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><title>Google Accounts</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

The message also includes at the end the following:

```
You are not authorized to perform this request
```

I attached below the code for this connection. As you can see there is a P12 file I am using in order to automatically connect to the Datastore service.

```
 $account = 'xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

 $key = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/../google-api-php-client/privatekey.p12');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($this->appId);

    $client->setAssertionCredentials(
            new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                    $account,
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore'),
                    $key)
    );


    $datastore = new Google_DatastoreService($client);
```

The thing is that I am not sure if it is a GAE problem or whether I can do something in my code to fix this or at least try to reduce the number of requests returning this error.

I have seen there is a new library release (1.0.1-beta), and we are planning to migrate to this version. However, before doing this it would be really useful to have any idea about what can be the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself, just in case anyone could find it useful.

After performing some tests I realized that the token returned after connecting was not being stored correctly. As a result, the system was trying to refresh the token in every single request. Apparently, after a given number of requests, Google just denies any new attempt to refresh the token for that user, causing the error I showed above.